# Generic types and compareTo method for strings

Tags: java, generics, junit

I implemented a heap in java. Class declaration looks like this:

```
public class Heap<T extends Comparable<T>> implements HeapInterface<T>
```

And methods that I wanted to test look like this:

```
@Override
public void put(T item) {
   if (item == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot put null item.");
   }
   items.add(item);
   int lastItemId = items.size() - 1;
   heapUp(lastItemId);
}


private void heapUp(int childId) {
    int parentId = (childId - 1) / 2;

    while (childId > 0 && isChildBiggerThanParent(childId, parentId)) {

        swapItems(childId, parentId);
        childId = parentId;
        parentId = (childId - 1) / 2;
    }
}
```

And I used comapreTo method:

```
private boolean isChildBiggerThanParent(int childId, int parentId) {
    T childValue = items.get(childId);
    T parentValue = items.get(parentId);
    return childValue.compareTo(parentValue) > 0;
}
```

Heap works fine for Integer, Double types and passed tests. But it doesn't work for Strings. Could you advice me what do i need to fix to make it work for strings also?

Comment: what happens when you try it with strings?

Comment: In Java String.compareTo methods comapres strings lexicographically. This isn't what you want. Your best bet is to override what you want ideally for Strings

Comment: heap condition is not maintain (for example it returns c,a,b instead of c,b,a)

Comment: @papaya could you give me a tip how i should do it?

Comment: I solved it. Thanks for help